# Линковка с флагом as-needed, статические переменные и загадочные крэши

Tags: c++, linux, компоновщик

Имеется с++ проект под linux, состоящий из оболочки, которая загружает различные модули, выполненные в виде shared библиотек (на самом деле это плагины загружаемые через QPluginLoader, но по сути те-же разделяемые библиотеки). Модули, в свою очередь используют методы друг друга. Компилятор clang 6, gold линкер.

Обнаружена странная проблема со статическими переменными. Например мы имеем три библиотеки L1, L2, L3. L1 и L2 используют L3. В одном из экспортируемых классов L3 задана статическая переменная:

```
test.h:
class AAA
{
public:
static QHash<int,int> data;
};

test.cpp:
QHash<int,int> AAA::data = {{1,2} , {2,3}};
```

Если проект линкуется без опции

> -Wl,--as-needed

то при закрытии приложения память, выделенная под AAA::data удаляется дважды, и естественно происходит крэш. Такое впечатление, что библиотеки L1 и L2, при линковке к L3, дважды генерируют код освобождения памяти. После активации -Wl,--as-needed, креши пропадают. Это вообще нормальное поведение?

Comment: бектрейс креша можно?

Comment: Сейчас выдать детальный не могу, но там срабатывает проверка MALLOC_CHECK внутри glibc и выдает corrupted double-linked list

Comment: если там выше по стеку какой-нить деструктор `QPluginLoader` или что-то подобное, то вероятно оный некорректно используется...

Comment: Нет, там в стеке один ассемблер. Суть в том, что проблема вылезла после смены системы сборки с qbs на cmake. На том же самом коде сборка под qbs(или qmake) не приводит к крэшам, а cmake - приводит. Я сравнил командные строки, которые генерят qbs/cmake - разница только в этом параметре линковки.

Comment: Про проблему можно почитать [тут](http://wiki.rosalab.com/ru/index.php/Overlinking) и далее по ссылкам оттуда

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку! Это похоже действительно оно.